# OSError: [Errno -128] NetCDF: Attempt to use feature that was not turned on when netCDF was built.: b'/content/test.hdf'

Tags: google-colaboratory, python-xarray, netcdf4

I downloaded MODIS data from its http server and was trying to load it in xarray on google colab. I added the `netrc` file and the file is not corrupted since `gdalinfo` on that gave no error.

```
URL = 'https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.061/2019.02.24/MOD09GA.A2019055.h09v07.061.2020288120208.hdf'

result = requests.get(URL)
filename = 'test.hdf'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(result.content)
```

when I run

```
xr.open_dataset('test.hdf',engine = 'netcdf4' )
```

this is the error

```
KeyError: [<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>, ('/content/test1.hdf',), 'r', (('clobber', True), ('diskless', False), ('format', 'NETCDF4'), ('persist', False))]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xarray/backends/file_manager.py in _acquire_with_cache_info(self, needs_lock)
    203                     kwargs = kwargs.copy()
    204                     kwargs["mode"] = self._mode
--> 205                 file = self._opener(*self._args, **kwargs)
    206                 if self._mode == "w":
    207                     # ensure file doesn't get overriden when opened again

src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__()

src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success()

OSError: [Errno -128] NetCDF: Attempt to use feature that was not turned on when netCDF was built.: b'/content/test.hdf'
```

What is the error about and how to resolve it?

`netcdf4 version 1.5.8`

`xarray version 0.18.1`